# Jquery Ajax PHP Json not working on centos server

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery, centos

I have been working on my local mamp server developing my website and today moved it over to a linux server running centos 6. Everything works fine except for the ajax requests.
The ajax request works correctly and I get a 200 result, however the on success event does not trigger.

I am returning an json encoded array so I can use the returned result in the js, but when I declare the dataType as Json things seem to stop working.

Here is my code:
Jquery Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/GetTarget.php?vId='+jsArray["vuforiaID"],
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (response1) {
                //alert(response1["status"]);
                      var msg = '<img src="/img/ajax-loader-small-blue.gif" /> Processing';
                      for (var i=0; i<parseInt(response1["rating"]); i++) {
                        msg = msg+'<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-star white"></span>';
                      }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$json = curl_exec($ch2);

$jsonResponse2= json_decode($json) ;

$returnData['status'] = $jsonResponse2->status;
$returnData['rating'] = $jsonResponse2->target_record->tracking_rating;
echo json_encode($returnData);
```

I have Json installed and running on PHP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there an error when you navigate directly to `GetTarget.php` with a valid ID? Is CURL enabled? Check the error_log (or custom log file) it is likely to be a PHP configuration issue.

Comment: When I navigate directly to GetTarget.php I see the output correctly with no errors. It might be a PHP configuration error but I see the Json is installed in phpinfo

Comment: Are you sending JSON headers? Try commenting out the `dataType` option and see if success is fired. Otherwise add the `.error()` function as described on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and see what the status message is.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
yum install js-jquery
```